# How to insert a record into a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

On a testing situation I need to insert a record into a MySQL table. I have used simply

`INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1','b')`

I kept value inputs aligned to the table structure but did not name the fields. Any downsides to this command? I could only find answers to complex record insert situations, that is why I ask.

Comment: _I could only find answers to complex record insert situations..._ There are mega mega mega tons of tutorials and examples out there - Take a look at [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Comment: I meant at stackoverflow, not tutorials

Comment: @AlMartins: What exactly are you asking?  If your syntax is valid?  That can be tested by executing the code and observing the results as well as checking against the MySQL documentation.  *When you test your code* do you encounter any problems?  We can help with those specific problems, if there are any.  But if you're just asking if your code is right then you can find out by testing it.

Comment: @David thanks. Trying to stick to stackoverflow on this one to save time. Really, only found answers to very complex record situations. Don't see the reason to name the columns

Answer (score 1):

The insert syntax in MYSQL and seems like you missed `VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Try update yours to below.

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1','b')
```